# how to python mimetypes.guess_type from a file-like object

Tags: python, mime-types

```
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('picture.jpg')
('image/jpeg', None)
```

Now I have a file-like object, (eg. stingIO),
which content is image's data

How can i detect the mimetypes from a file-like object

Comment: Can you check it before it turns a file-like object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The python mimetype standard module maps filenames to mime-types and vice versa.  To use it, you'll need a filename or a mime-type, in which case it'll give you back a possible file extension.

It won't/doesn't determine the mime-type based on a file's contents.  You need another type of tool to do that.  Libmagic, the library behind the unix file command, is one of those tools.  The filemagic module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic/1.6) is a python interface to libmagic.

```
import urllib2
import magic

img_data = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png').read()
# You can add flags 
# magic.Magic(flags=magic.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE) for take "/image/png"
m = magic.Magic()
print m.id_buffer(img_data)
m.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> print(mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type('my_file.txt')[0])
text/plain
```

Reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-Python

Answer (score -1):

```
def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            f = request.files['file']
            mime_type = f.content_type
```